# Erro ao gerar apk com google play services

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, google-play

Tenho um aplicativo que usa google maps, que funciona perfeitamente em modo debug. Mas quando gero o apk assinado, e instalo no aparelho os mapas não funcionam. O que pode ser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obrigado Lucas. Mas consegui resolver.
Quando criei um GoogleMapsActivity ele me mostra um arquivo google_maps_api.xml para incluir a minha chave de acesso. Porém esse arquivo é apenas para debug. Mudei a perspectiva para project e acessei a /app/src/realese/google_maps_api.xml onde o campo para chave estava vazia. Aí foi só incluir a chave de acesso que funcionou!

Answer (score 0):

Falando pelo meu conhecimento de assinaturas e essas coisas utilizando a Unity5, quando você gera um certificado para o aplicativo e assina ele mas não disponibiliza ele através da Google Play, o android reconhece que esse aplicativo é "pirata" e bloqueia automaticamente alguns serviços dele.

Para resolver esse problema eu tiver que criar minha conta de desenvolvedor na Google Play e disponibilizar o aplicativo lá em fase beta para não disponibilizar publicamente.

Não sei se é isso, mas para mim foi assim que eu consegui resolver esse tipo de problema quando eu estava utilizando o Google Play Game Services dentro do meu jogo! :D

Comment: Eu até publiquei no google play. Mas não funciona.